# No errors but app doesn't open

Tags: java, android

I am following the Android for Programms: App Driven Approach to make the tip calculator app, I have followed the code exactly as in the book and get no errors. However, when I try to run the app, I get the message, "Unfortunately, Tip Calculator has stopped."

Can anyone please help me find out why the app isn't opening?

```
package com.example.tipcalculator;


 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.SeekBar;
 import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
 import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String BILL_TOTAL = "BILL_TOTAL";
private static final String CUSTOM_PERCENT = "CUSTOM_PERCENT";

private double currentBillTotal; //bill amount entered by the user
private int currentCustomPercent; //tip% set with the seek bar
private EditText tip10EditText; //displays 10% tip
private EditText total10EditText; //displays total with 10% tip
private EditText tip15EditText; //displays 15% tip
private EditText total15EditText;//displays total with 15% tip
private EditText billEditText;
private EditText tip20EditText; //displays 20% tip
private EditText total20EditText; //displays total with 20% tip
private TextView customTipTextView; //dispalys custom tip percentage
private EditText tipCustomEditText; //displays custom tip amount
private EditText totalCustomEditText; //displays total with custom tip


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //check if app just started or is being restored from memory
    if(savedInstanceState == null)//the app just started running
    {
        currentBillTotal = 0.0; //initialize the bill amount to zero
        currentCustomPercent = 18; //initialize the custom tip to 18%
    }//end if

    else //app is being restored from memory, not execuuted from scratch
    {
        //initialize the bill amount to saved amount
        currentBillTotal = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_TOTAL);
        //initialize the custom tip to saved amounth
        currentCustomPercent = savedInstanceState.getInt(CUSTOM_PERCENT);
    }

    //get references to the 10%, 15%, 20% tip and total EditTexts
    tip10EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tip10EditText);
    total10EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.total10EditText);
    tip15EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tip15EditText);
    total15EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.total15EditText);
    tip20EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tip20EditText);
    total20EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.total20EditText);

    //get textview displaying custom tip percentage
    customTipTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.customTipTextView);

    //get teh custom tip and total EditTexts
    tipCustomEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.customTipTextView);
    totalCustomEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalCustomEditText);

    //get the billEditText
    billEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.billEditText);


    // billEditTextWwatcher handles billEditText's onTextChanged Event
    billEditText.addTextChangedListener(billEditTextWatcher);

    //get the Seekbar used to set the custom tip amount
    SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);

    customSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);
}

private  void updateStandard()
{
    //calculate bill total with a 10% tip
    double tenPercentTip = currentBillTotal * .1;
    double tenPercentTotal = currentBillTotal + tenPercentTip;

    //set tipTenEditText's text to tenPercentTip
    tip10EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", tenPercentTip));
    //set totalTenEditText's text to tenPercentTotal
    total10EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", tenPercentTotal));

    //calculate bill total with a 15% tip
    double fifteenPercentTip = currentBillTotal * .15;
    double fifteenPercentTotal = currentBillTotal + fifteenPercentTip;

    //set tip15EditText's text to fifteenPercentTip
    tip15EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", fifteenPercentTip));
    //set total15EditText's text to fifteenPercentTotal
    total15EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", fifteenPercentTotal));

    //calculate bill total with a 20% tip
    double twentyPercentTip = currentBillTotal * .2;
    double twentyPercentTotal = currentBillTotal + twentyPercentTip;

    //set tip20EditText's text to 20PercentTip
    tip20EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", twentyPercentTip));
    //set total20EditText's text to 20PercentTotal
    total20EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", twentyPercentTotal));
}

private void updateCustom()
{
    //set customTipTextView's text to match the position of the SeekBar
    customTipTextView.setText(currentCustomPercent + "%");

    //calculate the custom tip amount
    double customTipAmount = currentBillTotal * currentCustomPercent * .01;

    //calculate total bill, including custom tip
    double customTotalAmount = currentBillTotal + customTipAmount;

    //display the tip and total bill amounts
    tipCustomEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", customTipAmount));
    totalCustomEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", customTotalAmount));
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putDouble(BILL_TOTAL, currentBillTotal);
    outState.putInt(CUSTOM_PERCENT, currentCustomPercent);
}

//called when the user changes position of SeekBar
private OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
    //update currentCustomPercent, then call updateCustom
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
    {
        //sets currentcustompercent to position of the SeekBar's thumb
        currentCustomPercent = seekBar.getProgress();
        updateCustom(); //update EditTexts for custom tip and total
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
        //end method onStartTrckingTouch
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
        //end method onStopTracking Touch
    }
};

//event-handling object that responds to billEditText's events
private TextWatcher billEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{
    //called when the user enters a number
    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            currentBillTotal = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            currentBillTotal = 0.0;
        }

        updateStandard();
        updateCustom();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }
};





}
```

Here is the log cat:

```
07-06 13:10:34.590: W/asset(14247): Copying FileAsset 0x727a6928 (zip:/data/app/com.example.tipcalculator- 1.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 95268 to make it aligned.
07-06 13:10:34.670: W/dalvikvm(14247): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416ebe18)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247): Process: com.example.tipcalculator, PID: 14247
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.tipcalculator/com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
07-06 13:10:34.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14247):    ... 11 more
07-06 13:10:34.690: D/Process(14247): killProcess, pid=14247
07-06 13:10:34.690: D/Process(14247): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:131 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690 
07-06 13:10:50.410: W/asset(14400): Copying FileAsset 0x72751068 (zip:/data/app/com.example.tipcalculator-1.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 95268 to make it aligned.
07-06 13:10:50.520: W/dalvikvm(14400): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416ebe18)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400): Process: com.example.tipcalculator, PID: 14400
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tipcalculator/com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
07-06 13:10:50.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14400):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You get a ClassCastException here: `onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)`. This is an error!

Comment: I don't exactly know what that means

Comment: You're trying to cast a TextView as an EditView.  That isn't legal-  you can't cast something to a subclass.  Change the type of the variable or fix the cast.

Comment: @user3672089 I think the field `R.id.customTipTextView` is defined as an editText in your xml file. Please change it to  `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

The log clearly tells you what the problem is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

You are attempting converting a TextView field from your layout file to a Java EditText.

Check activity_main.xml to find the mal-defined field.

Comment: Also, sometimes if it looks like your layout is already using TextView (in this case) you may see this ClassCastException if you have reordered or shuffled some of the IDs in the layout. A build clean should remedy this.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your object as an `EditText`

```
private EditText tipCustomEditText; //displays custom tip amount
```

But then you find a View that is (probably) a `TextView` and try to cast it to `EditText`

```
tipCustomEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.customTipTextView);
```

Change these lines to:

```
private TextView tipCustomEditText; //displays custom tip amount
tipCustomEditText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.customTipTextView);
```

Accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
tipCustomEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.customTipTextView);
```

the ID name says `TextView` but your code try to cast to `EditText`.

Anyway to be more specific, it's here: `MainActivity.java` line 65